# Assembly: The need for saving values in a the memory stack in the following code and in general

Tags: assembly, mips

I'd love your help with the following problem.

I was asked to implement the function is_cube, which receives n as an argument and checks if it is a cube, in MIPS assembly. For example 8 (2^3) and 1000 (10^3) are cubes.

I wrote the following code:

```
# UNTITLED PROGRAM

.data   

str: .asciiz "Please enter your number >"
str1: .asciiz "The number is a cube"
str2: .asciiz "The number is not a cube"


.text

 main:  

   li $v0 4
   la $a0 str
   syscall

   li $v0 5
   syscall


   move $t0 , $v0
   li $t1, 0
   blt $t0, $zero, negative


  negative:
    sub $t5, $zero, 1
mul $t0, $t0, $t5



 is_cube: 

  addi $t1, $t1, 1
  sgt $t2, $t1, $t0
  bne $t2, $zero, There_is_not 
  mul $t3, $t1, $t1
  mul $t4 ,$t3, $t1
  beq $t4, $t0, There_is

  jal is_cube



 There_is:

   li $v0 4
   la $a0 str1
   syscall

   jal end

 There_is_not:

   li $v0 4
   la $a0 str2
   syscall

   jal end


 end:
```

and it works, without saving `$s0` in a stack by `$sp` and all of this process. My question is: Is it Ok not saving it? and if so, When should I use it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You're not using $s0 anywhere... Why would you save it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't implemented a function. You have implemented a loop, which happens to use `jal` instead of a normal branch instruction.   Execution starts in main and then falls through from `negative` to a loop starting at `is_cube`, and then when the loop terminates at `There_is` or `There_is_not` you use `jal end` instead of another branch instruction.

This code **happens** to work on MIPS because the `jal` instruction does not push the current value of the program counter to the stack, unlike the x86.

If this is homework, you should go back to your notes on writing functions in assembler before submitting this code.